# How to add rows dynamically by using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to add the row and column to the middle by using jquery?

I want add the rows when I click on add new button in the table.

And I want to remove the that row when I click on remove button.

please check the jquery function in that.

```
<tr>
    <td>Education</td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>School Name</td>
    <td>Degree/Diploma</td>
    <td>Field(s)of Study </td>
    <td>Date of Completion </td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr id="gradingMaster">
    <td> 
        <input type="text" id="firstname1" name="" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " value="${param.firstname}" onblur="letterOnly(this);" onfocus="this.value;"/>          
        <p id="firstname" style="color: red"/>
        <html:errors property="firstname"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input type="text" id="firstname1" name="" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " value="${param.firstname}" onblur="letterOnly(this);" onfocus="this.value;"/>          
        <p id="firstname" style="color: red"/>
        <html:errors property="firstname"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input type="text"  class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="datepicker3" name="dateofjoining"  value="${param.dateofjoining}"/>
        <html:errors property="dateofjoining"/>
    </td>
    <td>  
        <input type="text"  class="input-large datepicker" style="height:27px;" readonly="true" id="datepicker3" name="dateofjoining"  value="${param.dateofjoining}"/>
        <html:errors property="dateofjoining"/></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="education1321232"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addneweducation">Add New</button>
        </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { alert(4); var c = 1; $("#addneweducation").click(function() { alert(12); // $('#myTable').find('tbody:last') // var newtr = $(document.createElement('tr')); $('
<tr>some more HTML here</tr>').appendTo('tbody'); // var table = document.getElementById("education1321232"); // var rowCount = table.rows.length; // var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); // alert(rowCount); // row.append('
<td>
  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " />
</td>'); //// // row.append('
<td>
  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " />
</td>'); // row.append('
<td>
  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " />
</td>'); // row.append('
<td>
  <input type="text" name="" maxlength="200" class="input-large" style="height:27px; " />
</td>'); // ++c; // row.appendChild("#employeetable"); // ('#employeetable').find('tbody:last').appendTo("#employeetable tbody"); }); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a row using something like `.append()` or `.appendTo()`.  For example:

```
$('#addneweducation').click(function () {
    $('<tr>some more HTML here</tr>').appendTo('tbody');
});
```

It looks like your button is actually inside the table, so maybe you want something more like this:

```
$('#addneweducation').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').after('<tr>some more HTML here</tr>');
});
```

That would insert the specific HTML after the `tr` which is just before the `tr` which contains the button.  You can use [various other functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) and selectors to identify other locations to insert the new elements.

For removing a row, assuming that row *contains* a button to remove it (and assuming, for example, that button has a class of `remove` for the purpose of this example), something like this would work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

It basically finds the `tr` which contains the clicked button and removes that element.

Comment: @user3214269: In what way is it not working?  Please describe the problem.

Comment: I have used this $('#addneweducation').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').after('<tr>some more HTML here</tr>');
}); that row is not creating

Comment: @user3214269: What *is* it doing?  When you debug this, is the code executed at all?  In your updated question you just copied/pasted the new element.  Did you define the HTML for that element?  You need to do at least *some* debugging, I can't see your computer from here.